# Tengo este error en angular 'ER_PARSE_ERROR', errno: 1064,

Tags: api

Esta es mi función que envía los datos estoy trabajando con angular cli version 12.2

```
     onSubmit(){
    this.api.editPosition(this.editarPositionForm.value).subscribe(res=>{
     this.position = res[0];
      console.log(res)
    })
    this.editarPositionForm = this.formBuilder.group ({
         name:['',Validators.required],
         description:['',Validators.required]
      })
      this.editarPositionForm.reset();
  }
```

aquí esta la función de mi servicios de la API es donde recibo el form con los datos

```
      editPosition(form:RegistroPositionI):Observable<ResponseI[]>{
    console.log(form)
    let direccion=this.url+"/position/id";
    return this.http.put<ResponseI[]>(direccion,JSON.stringify(form))
  }
```

Así recibe los datos mis servidor para hacer el update pero me genera un error

```
    routes.put('/position/:id', (req, res)=>{
    req.getConnection((err, conn)=>{
        if(err) return res.send(err)
        conn.query('UPDATE position set ? WHERE id = ?', [req.body,req.params.id], (err, rows)=>{
            if(err) return res.send(err)
            res.send('Correcto')
        })
    })
})
```

El error que me genera es el siguiente

```
    code: "ER_PARSE_ERROR"
    errno: 1064
    index: 0
    sql: "UPDATE position set  WHERE id = 'id'"
    sqlMessage: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to 
    your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE id = 'id'' at line 1"
    sqlState: "42000"
```

Comment: No, el error no es en Angular. Es en la API. Es importante saber diferenciar en dónde ocurren los errores para llegar más rápido a una solución.

Answer (score 0):

Tal parece el problema se encuentra en esta parte:

```
routes.put('/position/:id', (req, res)=>{
req.getConnection((err, conn)=>{
    if(err) return res.send(err)
    conn.query('UPDATE position set ? WHERE id = ?', [req.body,req.params.id], (err, rows)=>{
        if(err) return res.send(err)
        res.send('Correcto')
    })
})
```

¿Puedes asegurarte que req.body sea un objeto y no un string?

Ya que al parecer envías la información como un string, pero creo que debería ser como un objeto (sin JSON.stringify).

```
  editPosition(form:RegistroPositionI):Observable<ResponseI[]>{
console.log(form)
let direccion=this.url+"/position/id";
return this.http.put<ResponseI[]>(direccion, form)
```

Cuando realices la operación te aconsejaría que valides que los datos que pasas en la consulta queden de la siguiente forma:

```
routes.put('/position/:id', (req, res)=>{
req.getConnection((err, conn)=>{
    if(err) return res.send(err)
    conn.query('UPDATE position set ? WHERE id = ?', [{
     name: 'valor name recibido',
     description: 'valor decripcion recibido'
},{
    id: 'valor del id'
}], (err, rows)=>{
        if(err) return res.send(err)
        res.send('Correcto')
    })
})
```

Saludos.